# Move installed R library to other directory

Tags: linux, r

Accidentally I have installed R library in my home directory

> /home/user/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library

And I want to move all this "/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library" thing to original R libraries directory.

I probably can't use `mv` as it will mess up everything.

What is the proper way of moving installed (R) libraries in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

You should give it the right permissions after moving them...

Use a package manager next time; or use one now, to ensure it's installed the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is to uninstall it then reinstall in the in the correct place.

It's really the only way to be sure you don't run into any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with both niffle and Tom, you really should just reinstall, doing something like this *might*, I say *might*, also work:

```
$ cp -rv /home/user/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library /usr/lib/R/library/
```

Then apply the same permissions you see in other sub folders of `/usr/lib/R/library/`.

Why do you want to move the files though? The library will work perfectly well from your $HOME and it will not be deleted if you upgrade your machine. Is there a particular reason you want to go to the trouble of moving it?